# jQuery: radio button name contains string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target a group of radio buttons that's name contains a part of a string...

```
if (!$("input:radio[name=PercentageValue]:checked"))
    alert("you need to check a percentage");
```

That isn't working...

Comment: If you could post the HTML as well, that would probably be helpful.

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do ? Select radiobuttons whose name does not contain string percentagevalue. Please be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery Contains Selector is `~=`

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Also, `$("input:radio[name=PercentageValue]:checked")` will always be `true`, try using `.is(":checked")` which will return a boolean like so:

```
if (!$("input:radio[name~='PercentageValue']").is(":checked")){
    alert("you need to check a percentage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!$("input:radio[name=PercentageValue]:checked").length)
    alert("you need to check a percentage");
```